# Modify function output in a plugin

Tags: plugins, functions, filters

I am trying to update one my plugin functions using add_filter with the ultimate goal of changing the order of elements that are output by the plugin.

Here is the plugin function:

```
public function stores_single_content($content) 
{
    global $post;

    if(!isset($post->post_type)) {
        return $content;
    }

    if ($post->post_type == 'stores') {

        $prefix = "wordpress_store_locator_";
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

        $args = array('fields' => 'names', 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC');

        // Categories
        $store_cats = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'store_category', $args);
        $categories = '<div class="store_locator_single_categories">';
            $categories .= '<strong class="store_locator_single_categories_title">' . __('Categories: ', 'wordpress-store-locator') . '</strong>' . implode(', ', $store_cats);
        $categories .= '</div>';

        $store_filter = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'store_filter', $args);
        $filter = '<div class="store_locator_single_filter">';
            $filter .= '<strong class="store_locator_single_filter_title">' . __('Filter: ', 'wordpress-store-locator') . '</strong>' . implode(', ', $store_filter);
        $filter .= '</div>';

        $address1 = isset($meta[ $prefix . 'address1' ][0]) ? $meta[ $prefix . 'address1' ][0] : '';
        $address2 = isset($meta[ $prefix . 'address2' ][0]) ? $meta[ $prefix . 'address2' ][0] : '';
        $zip = isset($meta[ $prefix . 'zip' ][0]) ? $meta[ $prefix . 'zip' ][0] : '';
        $city = isset($meta[ $prefix . 'city' ][0]) ? $meta[ $prefix . 'city' ][0] : '';
        $region = isset($meta[ $prefix . 'region' ][0]) ? $meta[ $prefix . 'region' ][0] : '';
        $country = isset($meta[ $prefix . 'country' ][0]) ? $meta[ $prefix . 'country' ][0] : '';
        $telephone = isset($meta[ $prefix . 'telephone' ][0]) ? $meta[ $prefix . 'telephone' ][0] : '';
        $mobile = isset($meta[ $prefix . 'mobile' ][0]) ? $meta[ $prefix . 'mobile' ][0] : '';
        $fax = isset($meta[ $prefix . 'fax' ][0]) ? $meta[ $prefix . 'fax' ][0] : '';
        $email = isset($meta[ $prefix . 'email' ][0]) ? $meta[ $prefix . 'email' ][0] : '';
        $website = isset($meta[ $prefix . 'website' ][0]) ? $meta[ $prefix . 'website' ][0] : '';

        $description = "";
        if($this->get_option('showAddressStyle') == "american") {
            $address = '<div class="store_locator_single_address">';
                $address .=  '<h2>' . __('Address ', 'wordpress-store-locator') . '</h2>';
                $address .= !empty($address1) ? $address1 . '<br/>' : '';
                $address .= !empty($address2) ? $address2 . '<br/>' : '';
                $address .= !empty($city) ? $city . ', ' : '';
                $address .= !empty($region) ? $region . ' ' : '';
                $address .= !empty($zip) ? $zip . '<br/>' : '';
                if($this->get_option('showCountry')) {
                    $address .= !empty($country) ? $country : '';
                }
            $address .= '</div>';
        } else {
            $address = '<div class="store_locator_single_address">';
                $address .=  '<h2>' . __('Address ', 'wordpress-store-locator') . '</h2>';
                $address .= !empty($address1) ? $address1 . '<br/>' : '';
                $address .= !empty($address2) ? $address2 . '<br/>' : '';
                $address .= !empty($zip) ? $zip . ', ' : '';
                $address .= !empty($city) ? $city . ', ' : '';
                $address .= !empty($region) ? $region . ', ' : '';
                if($this->get_option('showCountry')) {
                    $address .= !empty($country) ? $country : '';
                }
            $address .= '</div>';
        }

        $contact = '<div class="store_locator_single_contact">';
            $contact .=  '<h2>' . __('Contact ', 'wordpress-store-locator') . '</h2>';
            $contact .= !empty($telephone) && $this->get_option('showTelephone') ? 
                        $this->get_option('showTelephoneText') . ': <a href="tel:' .  $telephone  . '">' . $telephone . '</a><br/>' : '';
            $contact .= !empty($mobile) && $this->get_option('showMobile') ? 
                        $this->get_option('showMobileText') . ': <a href="tel:' .  $mobile  . '">' . $mobile . '</a><br/>' : '';
            $contact .= !empty($fax) && $this->get_option('showFax') ? 
                        $this->get_option('showFaxText') . ': <a href="tel:' .  $fax  . '">' . $fax . '</a><br/>' : '';
            $contact .= !empty($email) && $this->get_option('showEmail') ? 
                        $this->get_option('showEmailText') . ': <a href="mailto:' .  $email  . '">' . $email . '</a><br/>' : '';
            $contact .= !empty($website) && $this->get_option('showWebsite') ? 
                        $this->get_option('showWebsiteText') . ': <a href="' .  $website  . '" target="_blank">' . $website . '</a><br/>' : '';
        $contact .= '</div>
                    <div class="store_locator_single_clear"></div>';

        $map = "";
        $opening_hours = "";
        $opening_hours2 = "";
        $contactStore = "";
        if(is_single()) {

            $weekdays = array(
                'Monday' => __('Monday', 'wordpress-store-locator'),
                'Tuesday' => __('Tuesday', 'wordpress-store-locator'),
                'Wednesday' => __('Wednesday', 'wordpress-store-locator'),
                'Thursday' => __('Thursday', 'wordpress-store-locator'),
                'Friday' => __('Friday', 'wordpress-store-locator'),
                'Saturday' => __('Saturday', 'wordpress-store-locator'),
                'Sunday' => __('Sunday', 'wordpress-store-locator'),
            );

            foreach ($weekdays as $key => $weekday) {
                $open = isset($meta[ $prefix . $key . "_open"]) ? $meta[ $prefix . $key . "_open"][0] : '';
                $close = isset($meta[ $prefix . $key . "_close"]) ? $meta[ $prefix . $key . "_close"][0] : '';

                if(!empty($open) && !empty($close)) {
                    $opening_hours .= $weekday . ': ' . $open . ' – ' . $close . ' ' . $this->get_option('showOpeningHoursClock') . '<br/>';
                } elseif(!empty($open)) {
                    $opening_hours .= $weekday . ': ' . $open . ' ' . $this->get_option('showOpeningHoursClock') . '<br/>';
                } elseif(!empty($close)) {
                    $opening_hours .= $weekday . ': ' . $close . ' ' . $this->get_option('showOpeningHoursClock') . '<br/>';
                }
            }
            if(!empty($opening_hours)) {
                $opening_hours = '<div class="store_locator_single_opening_hours">' . 
                                    '<h2>' . __('Opening Hours ', 'wordpress-store-locator') . '</h2>' .
                                    $opening_hours . 
                                '</div>';
            }

            foreach ($weekdays as $key => $weekday) {
                $open = isset($meta[ $prefix . $key . "_open2"]) ? $meta[ $prefix . $key . "_open2"][0] : '';
                $close = isset($meta[ $prefix . $key . "_close2"]) ? $meta[ $prefix . $key . "_close2"][0] : '';

                if(!empty($open) && !empty($close)) {
                    $opening_hours2 .= $weekday . ': ' . $open . ' – ' . $close . ' ' . $this->get_option('showOpeningHours2Clock') . '<br/>';
                } elseif(!empty($open)) {
                    $opening_hours2 .= $weekday . ': ' . $open . ' ' . $this->get_option('showOpeningHours2Clock') . '<br/>';
                } elseif(!empty($close)) {
                    $opening_hours2 .= $weekday . ': ' . $close . ' ' . $this->get_option('showOpeningHours2Clock') . '<br/>';
                }
            }
            if(!empty($opening_hours2)) {
                $opening_hours2 = '<div class="store_locator_single_opening_hours2">' . 
                                    '<h2>' . $this->get_option('showOpeningHours2Text') . '</h2>' .
                                    $opening_hours2 . 
                                '</div>';
            }

            if($this->get_option('showContactStore')) {
                $contactStorePage = $this->get_option('showContactStorePage');
                $contactStoreText = $this->get_option('showContactStoreText');
                if(!empty($contactStorePage)) {
                    $contactStorePage = get_permalink($contactStorePage) . '?store_id=' . $post->ID;
                }
                $contactStore = '<div class="store_locator_single_contact_store">' . 
                                    '<a href="' . $contactStorePage . '" class="store_locator_contact_store_button btn button et_pb_button btn-primary theme-button btn-lg center">' . $contactStoreText . '</a>'. 
                                '</div>';
            }

            $map .= '<div id="store_locator_single_map" class="store_locator_single_map" 
                                data-lat="' . $meta[ $prefix . 'lat' ][0] . '" 
                                data-lng="' . $meta[ $prefix . 'lng' ][0] . '"></div>';
        }

        $content = $categories . $filter . $content . $address . $contact . $opening_hours . $opening_hours2 . $contactStore . $map;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

and the add_filter I've written for the functions.php:

```
function modify_store_output() {
$content = $contact . $address . $filter . $map . $content;
return $content;
}
add_filter ('stores_single_content', 'modify_store_output', 15);
```

Trying to understand why that's not working :(

Comment: Can you try changing the first line of your filter callback function to `function modify_store_output($content) {`

Comment: Can you show us the call to `apply_filters('stores_single_content', ...)`? I don't see it in your modified plugin code. In particular, what does it pass as arguments to the filter? You won't have contact, address, filter, map and content in-scope in your modify_store_output automatically: you'll only have them if they're passed by the filter call, or if you can unpack them from an object passed by the filter call.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created your filter yet.
You can't just filter a function.

You'll need to call the function [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/), and then you can use it in your `functions.php` file.

So above `return $content;` add something like this:

```
$content = apply_filters( 'my_content_filter_name', $new_content, $content );
```

Then, use it like this:

```
function modify_store_output( $content ) {
    $content = $contact . $address . $filter . $map . $content;
    return $content;
}
add_filter ('my_content_filter_name', 'modify_store_output', 15, 1);
```

Notice how `$content` is passing through the filter to the input of your `modify_store_output` function. Also, the `1` at the end of the filter is how many of these variables (arguments) you are passing through. In this case it is only one, but if you wanted to pass more arguments to your filter function you would increase the number to however many you are using in your [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) callback function.